# .NET 6 C# configuration section variation

Tags: c#, .net-core, configurationmanager

I am building a console app using .NET 6.
To load the settings I am using the Options Pattern and I want to create json config file with a collection of objects that has variations in one of its properties.

Example json:

```
{
  "Persons": [
    {
      "Name": "Josh Wink",
      "Information": {
        "SSN": "BC00020032",
        "VatId": "100099332"
      },
      "Characteristics": {
        "Gender": "male",
        "Age": 23
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "Peter Gabriel",
      "Information": {
        "SSN": "GH00092921",
        "VatId": "100003322"
      },
      "Characteristics": {
        "EyeColor": "brown",
        "HairColor": "black"
      }
    }
  ],
  "SomeOtherSection": "Some Value"
}
```

I thought of using an empty interface for the Characteristics property, but I don't know how to map this section using Configuration.GetSection().Bind() or Configuration.GetSection().Get

Here are the classes I created

```
class PersonsCollection
{
    List<Person> Persons { get; set;} = new();
}
class Person
{
    string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    PersonInfo Information { get; set; } = new();
    ICaracteristics? Characteristics { get; set; }
}
class PersonInfo
{
    string SSN { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    string VatId { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
interface ICaracteristics
{

}
class PersonCharacteristicsType1 : ICaracteristics
{
    string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    int Age { get; set; } = 0;
}
class PersonCharacteristicsType2 : ICaracteristics
{
    string EyeColor { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    string HairColor { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your classes. First of all, you are missing `public` access modifiers for properties.

Secondary binder can't bind your `ICaracteristics? Characteristics` property because it is an interface and binder does not know how to convert data to it. You can introduce concrete class here which will have all the possible properties:

```
class PersonsCollection
{
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set;} = new();
}
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public PersonInfo Information { get; set; } = new();
    public Characteristics? Characteristics { get; set; }
}
class Characteristics
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public int Age { get; set; } = 0;
    public string EyeColor { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string HairColor { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}

class PersonInfo
{
    public string SSN { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string VatId { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

And then handle the "types" in the code.

Comment: That is a kind of solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems if you want to keep the distinct derived classes you will need to put a discriminator in your JSON to hint to the serializer which derived class to instantiate.

See documentation on this approach here...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism